# Preferred way to remove whitespace from a string

Tags: python, string, whitespace

I want to remove all spaces from a string.

> " as fa   sdf sdfsdf "

The result would be:

> "asfasdfsdfsdf"

There are several ways I can think of to achieve this, and I'm wondering which one is the best.

1.

```
"".join(" as fa   sdf sdfsdf ".split())
```

2.

```
" as fa   sdf sdfsdf ".replace(" ", "")
```

And I assume that there are more.
Which one is preferred?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the best and most efficient method is the second version, `" as fa   sdf sdfsdf ".replace(" ", "")`, as evidence you can use the `timeit` module:

- `python -m timeit '"".join(" as fa   sdf sdfsdf ".split())'`

  **`1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.554 usec per loop`**
- `python -m timeit '" as fa   sdf sdfsdf ".replace(" ", "")'`

  **`1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.405 usec per loop`**

Comment: I think you mean "iteration(s)"?

Answer (score 4):

`replace("  ", "")` is the clearest and most succinct.

Comment: +1. This option should be chosen because it most clearly describes the *intent*. (You want to "remote the spaces", you don't want to "split and join the string with different separators").

Answer (score 4):

Use this for removing all white space at once:

```
import re

s = ' as fa   sdf sdfsdf '
s = re.sub(r'\s+', '', s)

s
=> 'asfasdfsdfsdf'
```

The advantage of this approach is that it eliminates all the spaces in-between characters - one, two, no matter how many there are, because the regular expression `r'\s+'` matches "one or more" whitespace characters - including spaces, tabs, etc.

Comment: But a regular replace will look at each letter one at a time and accomplish the same task of removing all spaces. Likely more efficient due to less computational complexity.

Comment: depends on your scenario, you might want to consider other kind of spaces like \r, \n, \t tab, or some very strange spaces like this one - "　" in Unicode. That said, a lot more has to be considered - you might want to have a white list instead of bad list.

Answer (score 2):

Using `replace` will not remove all whitespace characters (e.g., newlines, tabs):

```
>>> 'abc\t\ndef'.replace(" ", "")
'abc\t\ndef'
```

I prefer `string.translate`:

```
>>> import string
>>> 'abc\t\ndef'.translate(None, string.whitespace)
'abcdef'
```

EDIT: `string.translate` doesn't work for Unicode strings; you may wish to use `re.sub('\s', '', 'abc\n\tdef')` instead.

Comment: I think this method deserves more recognition (which is to say I should read the string module documentation). :)

Comment: @martineau, no, `string.translate` unfortunately doesn't work with Unicode strings (or work at all for deletion in Python 3).

Comment: @SamuelIsaacson, incorrect.  Python 3: `'abc\t\ndef'.translate(str.maketrans('','',string.whitespace))`.  The dictionary keys must be Unicode ordinal values (integers), not characters.

Answer (score 2):

regular expression

```
>>> str = "   as fa sdf sdfsdf  "
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\s', '', str)
```

Comment: +1 because it supports unicode and removes all kinds of whitespace not just space characters (and despite the fact that `str` was used as a variable name which hides the built-in type of the same name).

Answer (score 1):

`re.sub(" ","", s)` is my favorite.

Comment: re for a single char substitution? ouch...

Answer (score 1):

Just to throw another one in the mix:

```
from string import whitespace
ws = set(whitespace)
''.join(ch for ch in my_string if ch not in ws)
```

Comment: `''.join(ch for ch in my_string if not ch.isspace())`

Answer (score 0):

Regex is simple and it works. `split()` is slightly more complicated. Regex is preferred over `split()`.

Comment: I absolutely agree. But the question wasn’t about regex.

Comment: oops. was thinking about java when i replied to this.